# Decoding JSON with swift's Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm trying to download some JSON data from Wikipedia using their APIs and trying to parse it through swift's Codable. The url I'm using returns the following:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "pageids": [
      "143540"
    ],
    "pages": {
      "143540": {
        "pageid": 143540,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Poinsettia",
        "extract": "The poinsettia ( or ) (Euphorbia pulcherrima) is a commercially important plant species of the diverse spurge family (Euphorbiaceae). The species is indigenous to Mexico. It is particularly well known for its red and green foliage and is widely used in Christmas floral displays. It derives its common English name from Joel Roberts Poinsett, the first United States Minister to Mexico, who introduced the plant to the US in 1825."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in swift I have declared the following:

```
struct WikipediaData: Codable {
    let batchComplete: String
    let query: Query

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case batchComplete = "batchcomplete"
        case query
    }
}

struct Query: Codable {
    let pageIds: [String]
    let pages: Page

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case pageIds = "pageids"
        case pages
    }
}

struct Page: Codable {
    let pageId: Int
    let ns: Int
    let title: String
    let extract: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case pageId = "pageid"
        case ns
        case title
        case extract
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the above correctly models the data. Specifically,

```
let pages: Page
```

as there might be more than one page returned.

Also, shouldn't that be a dictionary? if so, what would the key be since it is data ("143540" in the above case) rather than a label?

I hope you could point me in the right direction.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `pageIds` are `String`s your `pageId` should be too. Its mesmerizingly simple to use a `Dictionary` at this point, in fact you can simply use

```
let pages: [String:Page]
```

and you will be done (and given a `Dictionary` with minimal effort). `Codable` alone almost seems a reason to pick up Swift. I am intrigued to see to what other interesting and elegant solutions it will lead eventually. It has already changed how I think about JSON parsing permanently. Besides: your `pages` *really want* to be a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Hey Patru, I was so 'mesmerized' that I could not think of using `String` for the dictionary key!!!! blame it on the red wine :) thank you so much. One side question, should the structs' members be declared as optionals? still not clear on the details of how Codable interprets things. thanks

Comment: @djeetee Unless they can be (validly) `null` in the JSON, there shouldn’t be a reason to make them `Optional`. If they are incorrectly `null` in the JSON, you will get a decode error (which is likely what you want).

Comment: As @ItaiFerber pointed out you _can_ (and _should_) use optionals, even in `struct`s _if_ (and probably _only_ if) they are valid. This will make sifting through your data a little more awkward, but _if_ your web service does provide you with a messy structure then you _should_ end up with a somewhat messy piece of code. I hope it does not in Wikipedias case. However the `Dictionary` will return optionals when subscripted, so you will have to deal with some of it anyways. Leave as much of it as a non-optional as you possibly can.